# How to get the nearest matching value in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have one table:

| Index | Month_1 |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | 12 |
| 02 | 09 |

A user input for month is taken. The user gives input 11.

How we can match the user input month to the nearest month?

In this case the output should be:

| Index | Month_1 |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | 12 |

Logic: The month given by user is 11. Nearby month present in the table is 12. So the output is 12 (in table format shown above).

Answer (score 0):

Subtract values, get absolute values and then get position of minimal value, last select rows, there is double `[]` for one row DataFrame:

```
a = 11
df = df.iloc[[df['Month_1'].sub(a).abs().argmin()]]
print (df)
  Index  Month_1
0    01       12
```